# SOAP Kit in Mule 3.7

Tags: api, security, soap, mule

I have a question on how to build aand it generated flows in the project.I did try generating the flows from WSDL and it seems to work fine. However, when I try to build a project from it prompted to choose the service and port name. I do have few questions on this approach. 
   1.From the example in https://docs.mulesoft.com/apikit/apikit-for-soap, How do I generate flows if my WSDL has multiple ports/operations? Attached an image for reference.
  2.How does the security work? Can I use CXF or java class to secure it?

Note: I do not want to use proxy as it requires a vCore in cloudhub.
Any insight from experts is appreciated.

Thanks, 
ROA[image: SOAPKIT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. How do I generate flows if my WSDL has multiple ports/operations? Attached an image for reference.

> Apikit doesnt' have outbox support for generating flows from multiple 
>   ports/operations. You could only pick one at a time (atleast as we speak now).
>
> Workaround: 1. you could generate another project by selecting
>   different service/port each time. Copy paste these flows to your
>   original project.
>
> Workaround 2. You could manually add the flows for the corresponding
>   service/port name by mimicking the original flows.

Q2. How does the security work?

> Mule supports various security schemes like http-basic auth, oauth
>   etc.. whichever is the preference, you could add the security
>   component before the SOAP-ROUTER, message processor.  see the example below. Refer this [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-the-spring-security-manager) for more information on security configuration.

```
<flow name="api-main">
    <http:listener path="/TshirtService/TshirtServicePort" config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" doc:name="/TshirtService/TshirtServicePort" />
<http:basic-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>   
    <apikit-soap:router config-ref="/TshirtService/TshirtServicePort/api-config" doc:name="SOAP Router"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
```

Comment: Thanks Senthil for the response.  Will try those options.